# performance of dart code in browser vs. VM

Tags: performance, browser, dart

I was surprised by the performance of my Dart code in the browser vs. the Dart VM.  Here is a simple example that reproduces the issue.

```
test('speed test', () {
    var n = 10000;
    var rand = Random(0);
    var x = List.generate(n, (i) => rand.nextDouble());

    var res = <num>[];
    var sw = Stopwatch()..start();
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        x[j] += i;
      }
      res.add(x.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
    }
    sw.stop();
    print('Milliseconds: ${sw.elapsedMilliseconds}');
  });
```

If I run this code with dart, I get somewhere around 140 milliseconds.  If I run the same code as a browser test with `pub run test -p "chrome"` ... I get times around 8000 milliseconds.

I am willing to wait for a 0.1 s calculation, but to wait 8 s for something in the browser, no -- it is basically unusable.  When I go in release mode, the performance in browser improve but it's still 10x slower.

Am I missing something?  Do I have to avoid any calculations in the browser?

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Browsers no longer allow high-resolution timers in an effort to thwart side-channel timing attacks.  This may be contributing what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting how slow this is.

The corresponding JavaScript code:

```javascript
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var n = 10000;
  var x = [];
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) x.push(Math.random());
  var t0 = Date.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      x[j] += i;
    }
    res.push(x.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
  }
  var t1 = Date.now();
  console.log("Milliseconds: " + (t1 - t0));
}());
```

runs in as little as ~20 milliseconds.

So, it looks like Dart is somehow triggering "slow mode" for its generated Javascript.

If you look at the generated code, it contains:

```dart
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
      if (j >= x.length)
        return H.ioore(x, j);
      t1 = x[j];
      if (typeof t1 !== "number")
        return t1.$add();
      C.JSArray_methods.$indexSet(x, j, t1 + i);
    }
    C.JSArray_methods.add$1(res, C.JSArray_methods.reduce$1(x, new A.main_closure0()));
  }
```

You can try to tweak this code, but the big cost comes from `C.JSArray_methods.$indexSet(x, j, t1 + i);`. If you change that to `x[j] = t1 + i;`, the time drops to a few hundred milliseconds. So, this is the problem with the current code.

(You can improve performance a little, ~20%, by making `x` a `List<num>` instead of a `List<double>`. I have no idea why that makes a difference, the generated code is almost the same, the `add` closure uses `checkDouble` to check the type instead of `checkNum`, but they have exactly the same body).

You don't have to avoid any computation in the browser. You may have to optimize a little for slow cases like this (or report them to the compiler developers, because this probably *can* be recognized and optimized, it just fails to be so for now). For example, you can change your list `x` of doubles to a `Float64List` from `dart:typed_data`:

```dart
var x = Float64List.fromList([for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) rand.nextDouble()]);
```

Then speed increases quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Dart tracking issue for this is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38705.

The performance of this kind of code has recently improved considerably and is much closer to the Dart VM.